# Docker LAMP with default hub images or one custom single Stack

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

There are a few tutorials on the internet, some use *docker-compose* and therefore combine e.g. PHP, MariaDB, and PHPMyAdmin, all from the original projects on hub.docker.com. This method is pretty fast and easy to configure. With one yml file, the whole lamp server basically runs as required.

```
version: '3'
services:
    php-apache:
        image: php:7.3.2-apache-stretch
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - D:\test\src:/var/www/html
        links:
            - 'mariadb'

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.1
        volumes:
            - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            TZ: "Europe/Rome"
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpwd"
            MYSQL_USER: 'testuser'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'testpassword'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'testdb'

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: "mariadb"
        restart: always
        ports:
         - 8181:80
        volumes:
         - /sessions
        links:
         - 'mariadb'
volumes:
    mariadb:
```

[Source (edited)](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-a-docker-based-lamp-stack-using-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

Others create one DOCKERFILE and put all apt-get commands within this file, like this one from [fauria/docker-lamp](https://github.com/fauria/docker-lamp/blob/master/Dockerfile).

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Fer Uria <fauria@gmail.com>
LABEL Description="Cutting-edge LAMP stack, based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Includes .htaccess support and popular PHP7 features, including composer and mail() function." \
    License="Apache License 2.0" \
    Usage="docker run -d -p [HOST WWW PORT NUMBER]:80 -p [HOST DB PORT NUMBER]:3306 -v [HOST WWW DOCUMENT ROOT]:/var/www/html -v [HOST DB DOCUMENT ROOT]:/var/lib/mysql fauria/lamp" \
    Version="1.0"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

COPY debconf.selections /tmp/
RUN debconf-set-selections /tmp/debconf.selections

RUN apt-get install -y zip unzip
RUN apt-get install -y \
    php7.0 \ ...
```

While the first one seems to be a lot simpler, the second one has a few redundancies (Debian for PHP, ubuntu for MariaDB, php-alpine for PHPMyAdmin).

So does Docker now run 3 servers? One for PHP, one for the Database and one for phpmyadmin? It feels like a waste of resources, isn't it?

Which method is the typical convention?

Comment: The advantage of having separate containers (apart from that being the original principle) is that you can mix and match versions of PHP and databases.  You can easily install 2 versions of PHP and run them either in parallel or swap over.  Same with database versions - create a new container for a new version and test it against the old version.

Comment: One very useful docker container I've found is [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/) which also allows you to manage them through a web interface.  I usually don't run the phpmyadmin/redis/rabbitmq containers unless I need them.  But can easily start them through a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation: "It is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by using one service per container" which will be easier to maintain, scale or update without affecting any other services.

> In docker these instances called `services` so the docker compose running each component as a service

Also you can read more about [Running multi-service in container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) if you need to know more about it

Regarding the resource usage it wont waste as much as you think because this is one of the advantages when you compare a virtual machine to a docker container as it uses the same kernel of the host and does not dedicate a specific resources like what vms do as they run a whole separate operating system

Comment: I guess it is indeed the nicer way as one can rely on the official images. Moreover I guess it does not need that much more resources, cause everything is quite lightweight.

Thank you for explaining the resource part also :)

Comment: @ptmr.io if this answer works for you don't forget to mark the question as answered. or if you need something else to be explained let me know

Comment: @Mosetafa Hussein sure, I'll wait 1 or 2 days for possible other opinions, but yours seems to be quite a hit :)